# How to perform the following tasks

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Using dataset msleep, plot a qplot against bodywt and sleep_total factors, and add a line using geo_smooth. Use qplot to draw a line applying a linear regression model to remove the standard error. Group by vore. Separate the model into multi-facets by vore.**

`qplot(bodywt,sleep_total,data=msleep)+geom_smooth(method="lm")+geom_path(aes(group=vore))+facet_grid(.~vore)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there:

```r
library(ggplot2)

qplot(x = bodywt, y = sleep_total, data = msleep) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(vore), nrow = 3, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Thamks a lot its working